# variable conversion and explaination in php and vb.net

Tags: php, vb.net, variables

I have some php code as below.

```
<?php
    $value = -1924050635;
    echo "before:".$value;
    echo "<br/>";
    $value = sprintf('%u', $value);
        echo "<br/>";
    echo "after:".$value;

?>
```

Before value is `-1924050635`

after value is `2370916661`

My problem is that what the [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) is doing here.

What i need to do if i want the above same php functionality in `VB.Net`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php integer type is always signed (and in your case 32 bit wide). I.e. you let sprintf(%u) interpret the bit/bye sequence of a signed integer as an unsigned integer.
You can do something similar in VB.Net by using the class [System.BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) to get the byte() representation of the signed integer and then create an unsigned integer from that sequence.

```
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim x As Integer = -1924050635
    Dim y As UInteger = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(x), 0)
    System.Console.Write("y=" & y)
  End Sub
End Module
```

prints `y=2370916661`

(I'm not a VB.Net expert - there might be simpler solutions)